# How To Protect MVC 5 ASP.Net application against HTTP Parameter pollution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, web

In the scope of web security reviews, we got a security scan assessment result from our provider which mentions HPP (Http Parameter Polution) as a vulnerability in the application. 
In our case, we are building a MVC5 application and i would like to have some advices on how to fix this. I know, it is about validating and checking the URL, but it would be great if i get a solution example. I want to centralize it in the application. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @SoftLogics, did you have a look on OWASP website?

Comment: @alaa_sayegh, yes i did. I have already some ideas, but i need to have a direct answer to avoid rescanning the application many times (scan after remediation).

Comment: @SoftLogics, i had the same issues before and i use a method in a controllerbase class to validate the URL in every request. I will paste it as answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this link:
http://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2009/05/client-side-http-parameter-pollution.html

This is the official definition from OWASP to this topic:

Reflected HTML Parameter Pollution (HPP) is an injection weakness vulnerability that occurs when an attacker can inject a delimiter and change the parameters of a URL generated by an application. The consequences of the attack depend upon the functionality of the application, but may include accessing and potentially exploiting uncontrollable variables, conducting other attacks such as Cross-Site Request Forgery, or altering application behavior in an unintended manner. Recommendations include using strict validation inputs to ensure that the encoded parameter delimiter "%26" is handled properly by the server, and using URL encoding whenever user-supplied content is contained within links or other forms of output generated by the application.

I created a ControllerBase class where all controller inherit it and in this class i implemented the OnActionExecuting method and in this method i validated the url aginst %26 and %3

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Url != null)
        {
            var queryUrl = Request.Url.Query;
            if (queryUrl.Contains("%26") || queryUrl.Contains("%3"))
            {
                var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"controller", "Error"},
                    {"action", "Index"}
                };
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(routeValueDictionary));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestValidationException exception)
    {
        var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Error" }, { "action", "Index" } };
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(routeValueDictionary));
    }
}
```

With this fix, I always get a clean scan back. 
Try it. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, it looks really great, and many thanks for the detailed description, very helpful!!